# Excel Workbook Corrupted and Repaired now sheet says out of Memory when codes error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, corruption

So I have Cut and paste (First Mistake) my .xlsm Workbook over the previous copy and it just disappeared, After refreshing the folder it was there again but corrupted, Excel Repaired the file saying that it repaired the cause of the problem which was "Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing7.xml part (Drawing shape)". Great! So I went back to working and when I execute this code it keeps giving an error and after that I get "Out of Memory" Errors and I cannot save the workbook.

I Am Running on a 64-bit excel an Have 8Gb of RAM so its maybe not actual memory. I have tried removing the code and using other code on another sheet but still does the same. Also when I save the workbook after removing the code. It corrupts again when opening

```
Private Sub BtnNoticeRemove_Click()

Dim Lastrow, a As Long

If Sheets("Admin").cbxNotice.Text = "" Then
   MsgBox "No data Selected"
   End
End If

a = 2

Lastrow = Sheets("BP").Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until a = Lastrow + 1

If Sheets("Admin").cbxNotice.Text = Sheets("BP").Cells(a, 19).Value Then
    Sheets("BP").Cells(a, 19).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Lastrow = Sheets("BP").Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("BP").Range("S2:S" & Lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("S2"), 
    Order1:=xlAscending
End If

a = a + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Thx for the feedback guys, Okay so I managed to recreate all my data an Macro codes. No Corrupt errors anymore, but I Still get a Out of Memory error on the code above, After the sort is completed, at the

`Sheets("Admin").cbxNotice.Text`

It gives the error

Comment: My advice? Get a fresh workbook and paste everything back there.

Comment: In addition to the comment above: Restart your computer to make sure there are no orphaned Excel instaces in your memory. If your workbook contains a lot of data try to use the binary xlsb format which is much more stable against file corruptions. I already had many corruptions in a regular use with the xlsx/xlsm format but never with xlsb. • Note that once a file was "repaired" by Excel that doesn't meant that it was successful. If a file was corrupted once I recommend to to start a new one to ensure a correct file.

Comment: Thx for the feedback guys, Okay so I managed to recreate all my data an Macro codes. No Corrupt errors anymore, but I Still get a Out of Memory error on the code above, After the sort is completed, at the 

`Sheets("Admin").cbxNotice.Text`

It gives the error

Comment: what is `cbxNotice`? Also when deleting cell / row, it is always preferred to go in a reverse loop. (i.e. From last row to Start row to avoid recursively changing last row to raise error)

Comment: Hi, I got it to work, The issue was cbxNotice was a listbox in a sheet that referenced from my Backpage Sheet, the issue was in the loop it deletes from the Backpage sheet that the listbox referenced from that cause my loop to just continue, it completely ignored the Until and variable a just went on until the program error ed "out of memory".

Comment: So What I did to make it work, was clear the reference from the listbox and add those values into the listbox with macro code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, The issue was cbxNotice was a listbox in a sheet that referenced from my Backpage Sheet, the issue was in the loop it deletes from the Backpage sheet that the listbox referenced from that cause my loop to just continue, it completely ignored the Until and variable a just went on until the program error ed "out of memory".

So What I did to make it work, was clear the reference from the listbox and add those values into the listbox with macro code